# how to remove unfamiliar solutions to a standard Sturm-Liouville problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

apologies if this question is answered somewhere else; i could not find it. I have an SLP of the form $$-y'' = \lambda y, 0<x<l$$ with initial conditions $$y(0) = y'(l)=0$$ it can be seen from the energy argument that $\lambda = \alpha^{2} > 0$, and the solution should be of the form $A\sin(\alpha (x+B))$. If we set $A = 1$ for simplicity and look at the B.C., we obtain $$\sin(\alpha (0 + B)) = 0$$ $$\alpha \cos(\alpha (l + B)) = 0$$ so that $$\alpha (l+B) = \frac{\pi (2n-1)}{2}$$ $$\alpha B = \pi n$$ solving for alpha and B, $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2l}$ and $B = 2nl$. This gives us eigenvalues(?) of $\alpha = \frac{\pi^{2}}{4l^{2}}$ and eigenfunctions of $$y_{n} = \sin(\pi (\frac{x}{2l}+n))$$ but this is extremely strage to me because the eigenvalues do not depend on n. this solution seems to solve the equation and B.C. as well, so I can't figure out where I went wrong. How can I recover a more reasonable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite the solution to the ODE as $y(x)=A\sin(\alpha x+C)$, where $C=\alpha B$ in your notation. Then $y(0)=0$ (with $A\neq 0$) implies
$$
\sin(C)=0 \implies C = 2k\pi\quad(k\in\mathbb{Z}), \tag{1}
$$
hence $y(x)=A\sin(\alpha x+2k\pi)=A\sin(\alpha x)$, that is, $C$ disappears from the problem. The second boundary condition, $y'(l)=0$, now implies
$$
\cos(\alpha l)=0 \implies \alpha=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{l} \quad(n\in \mathbb{N}). \tag{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the same $n$ in the two equation. You should write that:

$$\alpha B = \pi n \quad \alpha (l+B) = \frac{2m-1}{2}\pi$$

Solve for $\alpha$ and $B$ and you will have:

$$1 + \frac{l}{B} = \frac{2m - 1}{2n} \quad \implies B = \frac{2n}{2(m-n) - 1}l$$ and $$\alpha = \frac{2(m-n) - 1}{2l}$$

Comment: can i then combine m-n = k to be a single index? or do i need a double sum to express all the possible eigenfunctions?